# jQuery get path after change

Tags: jquery, input, path, upload

I have a input box and a file upload. After choosing a file I want to display the file path in the other input box.

I tried it here but it seems not to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/x7jzk0pg/32/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myFile').change(function(){
    $('#text2').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" value="" />
<input type="file" name="myFile" id="text2" value="" />
```

What did I forget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you have used same id for both input please change like below:-

Now its working fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myFile').change(function(){
    $('#text2').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" value="" />
<input type="file" name="text2" id="myFile" value="" />
```